# Regex to capture everything after first occurrence of special character for multiple fields

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am currently running the following regex to capture all field value pairs with in brackets of a message.  The following regex will work, except when multiple colons followed by a space are used in a field value, i.e. Field3 in the message below:

```
\[([^\]]*)\:[\ ]+([^]]*)]
```

Message being parsed:

```
Jul 27 03:50:30 HOST02 log-type 2022-07-27T09:50:30 [INFO] [Field1: thread1] [Field 2: default] [Field3: Name of Item:  Using a colon in Name] [Field 4: 36719] [Field5: 2022-07-27T09:00:01] [Field 6: 0:50:28.574] Message string.
```

Current result:

```
Field3: Name of Item = "Using a colon in Name"
```

Desired result:

```
Field3 = "Name of Item:  Using a colon in Name"
```

Comment: I think the repetition of the first character class should be non greedy  `\[([^\]]*?):[ ]+([^]]*)]` https://regex101.com/r/seq17B/1

Comment: Just exclude the  colon: `\[([^\]:]*)\:[\ ]+([^]]*)]` https://regex101.com/r/PZSI7m/1  (Both comments do the same thing by making the colon not match in the first character class)